# occurred configuring root project 'android'

Tags: android, cordova

I got an error when i use cordova build --release android

and this is the error on command prompt:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
         file:/C:/Users/arnold/Downloads/android-sdk_r24.3.4-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/arnold/Downloads/android-sdk_r24.3.4-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
```

can someone help me? this is really frustating
i have search google but many people have different error on configuration
i have update all installed file in android sdk.

Comment: did you find a soution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```